# I am unable to print all the output in the excle file

Tags: python, pandas

i am unable to print all output in excle file.
please guide
i am using pd.dataFrame and openpyxl
i am fatching data from excel file and i want to write all the out data in column and rows.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import csv
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis
input_file = open ("Sequence.fasta","r")
for record in SeqIO.parse(input_file,"fasta"):`my_sec= str(record.seq).rstrip('\\')
       analyse= ProteinAnalysis(my_sec)
       mol_weight = analyse.molecular_weight()
       count_amino= analyse.count_amino_acids()
       epsilon_prot = analyse.molar_extinction_coefficient()
       iso_point=analyse.isoelectric_point()
       ist_index=analyse.instability_index()
       aromati=analyse.aromaticity()
       gra_vy=analyse.gravy()
       flex=analyse.flexibility()
      writer = pd.ExcelWriter('protein_feature_data.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
      wb= writer.book
     df = pd.DataFrame({'sequence':[my_sec],
                'Molecular_Weight':[mol_weight],
                'Amino_Acid_Count':[count_amino],
                'molar_extinction_coefficient':[epsilon_prot],
                'isoelectric_point':[iso_point],
                'instability_index':[ist_index],
                'aromaticity':[aromati],
                'Gravy':[gra_vy],
                'Flexibility':[flex]})
                df.to_excel(writer)
                wb.save('protein_feature_data.xlsx')
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Please use this updated code. You can save the file with just `to_excel`. Also, the `df` creation and writing to file should be outside the for loop. If the `df` is created fine (cannot confirm as the `input_file` has not been shared, the data should be written to the output file correctly.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import csv
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis
input_file = open ("Sequence.fasta","r")
for record in SeqIO.parse(input_file,"fasta"):
    my_sec= str(record.seq).rstrip('\\')
    analyse= ProteinAnalysis(my_sec)
    mol_weight = analyse.molecular_weight()
    count_amino= analyse.count_amino_acids()
    epsilon_prot = analyse.molar_extinction_coefficient()
    iso_point=analyse.isoelectric_point()
    ist_index=analyse.instability_index()
    aromati=analyse.aromaticity()
    gra_vy=analyse.gravy()
    flex=analyse.flexibility()
df = pd.DataFrame({'sequence':[my_sec],
                   'Molecular_Weight':[mol_weight],
                   'Amino_Acid_Count':[count_amino],
                    'molar_extinction_coefficient':[epsilon_prot],
                    'isoelectric_point':[iso_point],
                    'instability_index':[ist_index],
                    'aromaticity':[aromati],
                    'Gravy':[gra_vy],
                    'Flexibility':[flex]})
df.to_excel('protein_feature_data.xlsx')
```